# How to manage users(dataflow) between php and openfire

Tags: php, android, web-services, xmpp, openfire

I want to make a web application in php for Android, with a chat functionality.

I google for it and I found that `openfire` is usefull. But I am confuse in how to manage users between php and `openfire`. I means when create new user in web how to assign that client in openfire?

**UPDATE**

As my understanding by google search Dataflow is :

**For create user**

- create user in my web's db
- call openfire's api for create user in openfire.

**for update user**

- update user in my web's db
- call openfire's api for update user in openfire.

**Is this right process ?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No one have answer for this?

Comment: Finally I found soltion from https://www.dbbest.com/blog/chat-application-solutions/

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Openfire source docs and you will find ways of implementing your own AuthProvider - write some simple java code that talks to your PHP service and authenticates against it.

You will then need to set the Custom AuthProvider as your Primary auth provider in Openfire and the in-built auth as Secondary.

Comment: I don't know java. so i use openfire's api plugin.I updated my question as my understanding.